# Need help extracting AP_Pack .obb files

Tags: windows, decompilation, android, file-format, unpacking

I'm trying to extract the files for the series of 4 games - Sorcery!, which are in the format .obb.

Thanks to a Hex editor I saw that the .obb was an AP_Pack, and looking for more information on the internet I saw that someone on GitHub had created a specific extractor for this game: https://github.com/flamewing/sorcery-xtractobb

Unfortunately, very few details are given and I don't know what I should do.

It seems to use the Android .obb files of the game but someone in the Issues section confirms that it works with the .obb files of the PC version of the game, and even with another game from the same developer.

If anyone could explain or point me in the right direction, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to RE.SE. Although your question looks ok - its nothing more than mention of a github project. You didn't even mention what happens when you run this tool against your files. I won't download the files or build and run this tool for you. Please add details as to what you tried and where you failed?